# Sleep even if script is "interrupted"?

Tags: php

Is it possible to make something sleep in PHP, while making sure it executes it even if the script gets interrupted?

```
<?php
    //let's delete something
    echo 'Deleting something in 10 seconds';

    sleep(10);

    file_put_contents("newfile", "content here");
```

Basically I want to tell the user "Your file is being deleted in 10 seconds" and then do the `file_put_contents()` right after (I know, but this is just an example and not what I really do).

I don't want to timeout the user or make the site look like it loads or anything. When they request the page, it should echo something to the user and do the `file_put_contents()` 10 seconds after. Is that possible? Right now it won't echo anything or do anything, because it sleeps the entire script for 10 seconds.

Comment: With interrupted you mean a disconnect from the client before the 10 seconds runs out?  if so then you can use php function ignore_user_abort() read http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: @RaymondNijland I simply mean if I go to `website.com/delete.php` or whatever, it should `echo 'Deleting file in 10 seconds';` and then "execute another command" after 10 seconds. It should not care if the user closes the window, refreshes the page, or anything like that. I basically want a "cronjob" in PHP, if you see what I mean.

Comment: ok you can use ignore_user_abort() to keep the script running when the user is closing the browser or hits the refresh button.

Comment: @MortenMoulder Maybe you'r looking for `ignore_user_abort()`

Answer (score 0):

However I believe that you need to do such stuff from the client side, the `PHP` way is by making use of [`Output Control`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)

```
if($_GET("delete")) {

    ob_implicit_flush(1); // turn on the implicit flush

    echo 'Deleting something in 10 seconds';

    ob_end_flush(); // perform printing some immediate output 

    sleep(10);

    file_put_contents("newfile", "content here");
}
```

---

#### Update

the above solution will works fine in apache, for nginx you will need to add this option to your nginx.conf

```
fastcgi_keep_conn on;
```

**or** by adding this header to your file

```
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
```

Comment: `Call to undefined function ob_flush_end()` I'm getting this error

Comment: No error anymore, but it does not echo immediately. It waits 10 seconds, then echos, and then deletes. I need it to echo immediately.

Comment: `ob_implicit_flush(1);

echo 'Hello';

ob_end_flush();

sleep(5);
echo ' World';` consider this example please, execute it in your browser and check out

Comment: Doing THAT will not work. Since PHP gets compiled and so on, it would not echo after 5 seconds but rather wait 5 seconds then echo Hello and then World at the exact same time.

Comment: have you tried that? and please make sure that you've turned on the implicit flush `ini_set('implicit_flush',1);` and mostly flush does not work probably under apache gzip module, make sure that you've disabled it too , `ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0)`

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. I did turn that on and off, but when I request the page, it hangs for 10 seconds then does `echo 'Hello';` and then it fires the command right after. I need it to `echo 'Hello';` IMMEDIATELY when the page loads.

Comment: this is a strange behavior, it's works fine in my side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144123/discussion-between-mortenmoulder-and-hassan).

Answer (score 0):

Using [pcntl_signal](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) you could catch if script has been interrupted. Note it won't work with SIGKILL signal.

```
<?php

declare(ticks = 1);

//Remembering current time (if script will be interrupted we will compare it to determine how much time must we wait)
$startSleepAt = time();

//Setting handler for SIGINT signal
pcntl_signal(SIGINT,  function($signal) use ($startSleepAt) {
    //Waiting for remaining time
    sleep(time() - $startSleepAt);
    //Do your stuff here
});
sleep(10);
```

Comment: I do not have PHP compiled with pcntl_signal enabled, unfortunately. Also, would this allow me to echo onto the page IMMEDIATELY WHEN THE PAGE LOADS and then execute something else 10 seconds after? Like an `error_log()` just to make it simple.

Comment: So I would be able to: `echo 'Hello';` to the user immediately, then fire a `error_log()` after 10 seconds? That's all I need and so far it looks like it's not possible with PHP.

Comment: Yes. So in signal handler you need to place
echo(); sleep(10); error_log();. 
But are you sure you still have interrupt signals, especially in the web script? Because I doubt you have any interrupts there.

Comment: No, I think the whole "interrupted" part should be left out. There is essentially nothing that can interrupt a page that has been loaded which doesn't hang on a request. Take the interruption out of the equation and focus on "echo then error_log".